# BeautifulSoup export

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I am running the code below and getting an output that looks like the following

```
class="widget" id="dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__classification_code__widget">\n\tR -- Professional, administrative, and management support services\n\t\t
```

all I want is Professional, administrative, and management support services

How can I get rid of all the other text included in the output? I am using BeautifulSoup in Python

```
i = "https://www.fbo.gov/index.php?s=opportunity&mode=form&id=50e3e1ec75e2aaa7c4fca7761e4c46a2&tab=core&_cview=1"
response = requests.get(i)
textfield = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(textfield, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find_all(attrs={'id':'dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__classification_code__widget'})
tags
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`soup.find()` fetches you an entire HTML `Tag` object from the HTML source. You should use `.text` param or `.contents` array of the `Tag` object to get the text you need. 
`strip()` part will consequently remove the `\n\t` tags from the string.

One more tip: I would use `soup.find()` for this part of the code. `find_all()` can return an array of objects matching the search condition. As you are searching for an id, you should be expecting to get a single element as a response, thus `find()` is a more appropriate function.

```
i = "https://www.fbo.gov/index.php?s=opportunity&mode=form&id=50e3e1ec75e2aaa7c4fca7761e4c46a2&tab=core&_cview=1"
response = requests.get(i)
textfield = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(textfield, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find(attrs={'id':'dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__classification_code__widget'}).text.strip()
tags
```